# ¿como puedo solucionar este problemas?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.0

me podrían hacer el favor de ayudarme a solucionar este pequeño inconveniente, soy algo nuevo en esto. muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No uso java, pero no te esta faltando pasarle un parametro en el constructor? luego de especialidad y antes de documento.

Comment: sii pero ese es el error que tengo y que quiero que me ayuden, por eso señale con una flecha el tipo de dato que me esta pidiendo

Comment: Segun veo te esta faltando un objeto del Tipo ClinicaVo, que seria una clase como es Especialidad.

Comment: si exactamente, es que estoy jtexfield de tipo string, pero en si me esta es ´pidiendo un tipo de dato clinicaVO y ahi es el royo en el que estoy ejeje, como podria solucionar ese error muchas gracias por su atencion

Comment: Tal como lo comentan falta un objeto de tipo `ClinicaVo` para lo cual esa clase ya debe existir por lo tanto seria agregarlo, para mas ayuda en lugar de una imagen, te recomiendo que agregues código o si puedes especificar un poco mejor tu pregunta

Comment: Te deberia ayudar alguien de java, pero seria algo comun, instanciar un objeto de esa clase, llenar con datos sus parametros y luego ese objeto se lo pasas al constructor que te da error.

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista parece ser que te hace falta colocar el objeto `ClinicaVO` por lo tanto deberías tener ya creado dicha clase con su respectivos constructores o constructor.
Algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
public class ClinicaVo {

    private String nombreClinica;
    private String direccion;
    private String telefono;

    public ClinicaVo(String nombreClinica, String direccion, String telefono) {
        this.nombreClinica = nombreClinica;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
}
```

### 1. Creamos el objeto

```
ClinicaVo clinica = new ClinicaVo("Nombre de clínica", "Dirección de ejemplo", "1234567890");
```

### 2. Pasamos el objeto como parámetro

```
PersonalSaludVO personal = new PersonalSaludVO ( especialidad, clinica, "documento","nombre", "dirección", "Genero", fecha );
```